# How to power and mount flashes?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash

I just purchased a few Yongnuo YN-560 II flashes for use with a light tent (for macro photos) and as this will be my first time using external flashes I'm not quite sure how to power or mount them. So, basically, I have two questions:

1. I will be using these at a fixed location, so I would much prefer to power these via an AC wall outlet. Is that possible? what type of adapter would I need to buy?
2. I am planning on putting one on either side of the light tent and one pointing down from the top. What would be the best way to mount them in these locations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the mounting, do yourself a favor and get a couple of light-duty light stands that can extend to at least seven feet, along with a couple of tilt flash/umbrella adapters. If you don't need to support studio strobes with heavy modifiers, stands can be gotten pretty cheaply, and the tilt adapters can often be picked up for about ten bucks a unit or less. Not only will they be able to work with your light tent, you also be able to use them for just about any routine lighting setups you'll encounter. If a perfectly consistent setup with the tent is required, you can always mark the position of the stands and put witness marks (with a paint marker or a scratch awl, depending on the stand) on the risers and the flash adapter for later reference.

I'm not aware of any AC adapter that will work with the Yongnuos. Keep in mind that the current draw during recycling is very high, so the typical "wall wart" won't really be up to the task, and if the power supply provides a current that is higher than low internal resistance batteries can provide, you are likely to trip the thermal protection ciruit regularly (at best). Despite the inconvenience, you'd probably be better off with rotating (rechargeable) batteries through the units.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Stan. Do you know if the batteries go directly into the Yongnuos, or whether I need to buy some sort of battery pack for them? As far as inexpensive stands go, do you have any recommendations? Thank you!

Comment: @Nate - There is an external "booster" battery pack available to get a higher refresh rate, but they'll take four AAs internally without any accessories and thank you for them. The current "best practice" is to use a low-self-discharge NiMH like Sony's Eneloop --- they can provide enough current for fast recycles and don't have much in the way of "memory" problems.

Comment: +1 Great answer @StanRogers, but [Eneloop batteries are made by Sanyo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eneloop), not Sony. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is possible to have the Yongnuo YN-560 II with external CF-18 batt. pack $100 not incl  batteries on continual charge by splicing the charger into the external cable.

A 2m adjustable stand with a hot shoe is essential and/or suspended rails with drop [**hot-shoe fitting**](http://www.hawkwoods.com/products/details/details.php?code=dc-15a&mainMenuItemToSlide=17&asi=vl-dc5&asi2=vl-dc5x)s from the ceiling can free up floor space for multiple flash locations.